# wifi connected, but no internet access after update, i've tried it all

Tags: wireless, ath9k

After an update on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS I've lost internet access although I can see the WiFi connection.

I've tried all the solutions I could find on Google and on this forum, but nothing worked.
I know that a lot of people had had trouble with ath9k drivers, but I cant find a solution.
I tried to find a way to reset Ubuntu as when I first installed it, but there isn't. I thought there could be a solution.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this driver and solved it installing the backports... the steps that I followed are here: [Can't reach wi-fi signal on Ubuntu, but can do it on other OS/devices (ath9k)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices)