# Can't reach wi-fi signal on Ubuntu, but can do it on other OS/devices (ath9k)

Tags: wireless, drivers

I have two laptops, both running Ubuntu 13.10, as well as a different OS (Windows 7), dual boot on both.

My wi-fi router is on my bedroom and I want to get the wi-fi signal from the living room. I can reach the wi-fi signal from both pcs when running windows, with a relative good signal, but can't reach it on both of them when running Ubuntu, can't even connect to it.

Is there something that I can do to amplify the wi-fi signal?

Comment: Now I'm using Xubuntu, it works perfectly, I had similar issues. my old question may help you http://askubuntu.com/questions/253257/ubuntu-doesnt-reconnect-to-wifi-unless-i-reboot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, we solved it!

Using Atheros driver ath9k. If you have the same problem, please follow these steps (I found it [here](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1160188)):

1. Open the Terminal
2. Install the build dependencies if you don't have it already (but it is installed by default):

   `sudo apt-get install build-essential`
3. Type the commands (steps 3-9): `wget http://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/kernel/projects/backports/2014/01/31/backports-20140131.tar.xz`

   - Here you can get the latest ones from kernel.org site, but this version corrected the issues and it is the latest at the moment of this post!
4. `tar xvf backports-20140131.tar.xz`
5. `cd backports-20140131/`
6. `make defconfig-ath9k`
7. `make`
8. `sudo make install`

   - (type your password)
9. `sudo update-initramfs -u`

   - (type your password if needed)
10. Reboot your pc.

Remember that after a Kernel update (`sudo apt-get dist-upgrade`) we have to repeat the steps 4 to 9.

**This is useful for Atheros wireless cards, but if you have some issue with other manufacturers, try installing the backports drivers for them from kernel.org**.