# University wifi quietly disconnects on AR9285

Tags: wireless, networking, atheros

I have trouble with Ubuntu 13.10 on my university wifi. I connect, and it works fine for five seconds to five minutes, then the connection quietly disappears. It does not indicate that anything is wrong with the network, no "Connection lost", et cetera. It just reports that I am still connected to the network, but doesn't actually work. A solution is to disconnect the wifi, then reconnect, giving me a few moments more of working wifi - horribly annoying.

### Wifi stats

- WPA(2) Enterprise
- PEAP authentication - version automatic
- I have the university .CRT certificate installed; I hear it's unnecessary
- MSCHAPv2 inner authentication
- Username ...
- Password ...
- Typically three out of four bars signal strength in my dorm room.

### Other notes

- Lenovo G770 laptop
- Works fine in Windows 8
- Have tried Ubuntu 13.04, Linux Mint, Fedora, all have same problem
- Have tried other cards:
- - Atheros RTS5139 USB - same problem
- - Intel Wireless AC 7260HMW MiniPCIe - same problem AND lagged my PC horribly; removed
- My roommate reports similar issues with a Broadcom card
- I *think* it worked okay for a month or two when I joined university, only to suddenly begin acting in the mischievous manner I describe, after several fresh reinstalls.
- I am fairly experienced with Linux and have been using it since Ubuntu 8 or somewhere along those lines.

Do you have any ideas? I've been stuck using Windows and it sucks so bad. I'm desperate enough to consider buying a router and trying some bridge method... if nothing else would that work?

### lspci output

```
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter (PCI-Express) (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Device 30a1
    Kernel driver in use: ath9k
```

Comment: I had issues with ath9k and solved it following the steps as in http://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices

Comment: OMG! You have saved my college experience from Windows hell! I love you platonically and otherwise!

Comment: Is there any solution for the initial problem which was that your wifi was disconnecting after a short amount of time?

Comment: I'm sure there are many issues that can cause disconnects after a short amount of time, and thus there are many solutions. I personally used Kassius's link and it worked for me, but that particular solution might not help you (especially if you don't use ath9k).