# Wifi local connection or unstable connection only

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, dell-vostro

First time posting here, and one-week on Ubuntu 12.04 (on linux, in reality).
I'm having problems with my wireless connection at home only. At the university I can use wireless no problem, but at home it never connects beyond local and/or connects for 5-10 mins and stops working. I know my wifi card is not hard-blocked, from a few commands I saw over the forums to check. The driver I'm using is the default linux driver ath9k, and my wifi card is Qualcomm Atheros AR9285 Wireless Network Adapter. Searching for it have not wielded me any results...

At home, the wifi is distributed through a router, that I think might be the source of the problem. I have a dual boot machine, with a Windows 7 on it, and it works fine. So I know the router is not broken, but may not be corrected configured for the Ubuntu OS.

I even tried installing ndiswrapper to see if Windows drivers could help me, but I wasn't able to get it installed (can't find linux-headers, although they are there...).

Any ideas what might be the issue?
I can provide any additional information required.
Appreciate any help.

Regards,
Mihael Souza.

Comment: appears to be a duplicate of: [University wifi quietly disconnects on AR9285](http://askubuntu.com/questions/411263/university-wifi-quietly-disconnects-on-ar9285?rq=1)  which points to [Can't reach wi-fi signal on Ubuntu, but can do it on other OS/devices](http://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What eventually resolved the issue was following the steps in the link virtualxtc shared from Kassius:
[Can't reach wi-fi signal on Ubuntu, but can do it on other OS/devices (ath9k)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices-ath9k)

Regards,

Mihael Souza.