# Internet and perhaps even wireless connection gets disconnected intermittently

Tags: 12.04, wireless, networking, atheros

I am new to Ubuntu.
I bought a Dell 3537 - preloaded with ubunbtu. After, upgrading to the latest updates, my wifi stopped working. I found https://www.kernel.org/pub/linux/ker...able/v3.9-rc4/ and installed the driver. But, I observe the following:

Internet works absolutely fine for few minutes and then gets disconnected for few seconds. This keeps happening. I am pretty sure that connection to the wifi also is disconnected, but that isn't reflected in my network manager. My other laptop which runs Windows 7 doesn't have any issues connecting to the same network

I have tried to gather some information, which might help to solve my problem. Any help is appreciated.

It it helps, I have ran the script developed by Wild Man & Krytarik, helped by anewguy, chili555, llua and mentioned [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=12350385#post12350385)
The output is at - http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/7101870/

***uname -a***

```
Linux PK-LAPTOP-UBUNTU 3.5.0-47-generic #71~precise1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Feb 19 22:02:52 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
lsb_release -a
Code:
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID:    Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 12.04.4 LTS
Release:    12.04
Codename:    precise
```

***sudo lshw -C network***

```
*-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8101E/RTL8102E PCI Express Fast Ethernet controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 07
       serial: 74:86:7a:50:53:60
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=r8169 latency=0 multicast=yes
       resources: irq:60 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:c0700000-c0700fff memory:c0400000-c0403fff
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 01
       serial: 80:56:f2:94:40:b3
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=3.5.0-47-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.2 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
       resources: irq:19 memory:c0600000-c067ffff memory:9fb00000-9fb0ffff
```

***iwconfig wlan0***
**WHEN CONNECTED:**

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"tata"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 28:28:5D:35:E9:2C   
          Bit Rate=2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-38 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:61  Invalid misc:1   Missed beacon:0
```

**WHEN DISCONNECTED:**

```
wlan0     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"tata"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 28:28:5D:35:E9:2C   
          Bit Rate=121.5 Mb/s   Tx-Power=16 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=70/70  Signal level=-27 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

Comment: I had a friend with a similar problem, but on another machine. Do you have a USB-key for Wifi near you ? You should try it : for my friend, the internal wifi-chipset was overheating because he was too close to the graphic card.

Comment: @MrVaykadji u mean an external USB wifi adapter? No, I don't have one. I really doubt it is bcoz of overheating. I think it is some driver issue with  Qualcomm Atheros.

Comment: I own the Qualcomm Atheros AR2427 in my EEEPC and it works fine. Never had any issues with it, except on Windows XP

Comment: Please see the related thread on http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2211433

Comment: see if this helps http://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices-ath9k