# Can't install ath9k WiFi drivers

Tags: ubuntu-drivers, ath9k

When I try to `make`, I get the following errors:

[image]

Comment: Please try this http://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices-ath9k