# Wi-fi suddenly stopped working, for no apparent reason

Tags: 16.04, networking, wireless, internet

It had been working just fine until now, but I've tried every solution and sequenceo of commands I've found and nothing seems to work (though I admit I barely understood most of the solutions I've read).

The wifi icon flashes like it's connecting, stays like that for a long time, and eventually stops trying. Sometimes, upon trying to connect to my home network, it just stays fixed on a random bar and never does anything.

Here's what comes out of the commands recommended while posting the question:

[pastebin](https://pastebin.com/jUYhBiHr)

Comment: did you recently update your kernel?

Comment: I ran sudo install linux-generic because I saw it as a solution on this site, but I didn't touch that before.

Comment: it is possible the card failed. or drivers are incorrect. can you post the results of `sudo lshw -C network`

Comment: Here: https://pastebin.com/GxYuSXyQ

Comment: driver=ath9k driverversion=4.4.0-83-generic firmware=N/A latency=0 link=no ----  looks like firmware is missing, try reinstalling the driver

Comment: I think it's solved. I did this:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/406531/cant-reach-wi-fi-signal-on-ubuntu-but-can-do-it-on-other-os-devices-ath9k

I don't know if there's anything else necessary, but it's working now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you using a Virtual Machine of some sort to run your Ubuntu?

If you are using a VM, then check your VM setting to make sure it can connect to your desired connection. If you are not connected to a VM, then try to click on your network and click "Forget Network" and try to reconnect to it. before that you may want to try to restart your network manager with this terminal command:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

Comment: No, I have a laptop that runs ubuntu alone. I've already tried that command but it just starts trying to connect again and never does.